# How do I hide certain taxonomy boxes from users in admin add post page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin

I would like to hide this particular taxonomy box in the admin on the add new post page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me in functions.php

```
/**
 * [remove_meta_boxes remove the resource type standard meta box from the side sortables in the resource post edit screen
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function remove_meta_boxes(){
remove_meta_box( 'resourcetypesdiv', 'resource','side'  );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\remove_meta_boxes');
```

Comment: That is going to remove the box for all users. Is that what you intended? Shouldn't a user or role-- admins for example-- have access?

Comment: I intended it to be removed for all users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I assume its your meta box while adding new post:

Please go to `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php` and there are screen options at top of new post form like screenshot where you can hide things according to available options.

[image]

You can uncheck things you don't want in post form.

We can remove by codes as well, please follow this helpful post for details:

[*Remove Wordpress Meta Boxes* - WPMUDev.org](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/remove-wordpress-meta-boxes/)